# Ansible - use fact from local host in remote host template

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a playbook that contains roles for localhost and roles for remote hosts.

In one of the localhost roles I set a fact called `git_tag`.

I want to use this fact in a template for the remote hosts.

I tried:

```
- name: Read Version
  set_fact:
    git_tag: "{{ package_json.stdout | from_json | json_query('version')}}"
  delegate_to: "test-server"
```

But when Ansible reaches the role that reads the template that has `{{ git_tag }}` it says that `git_tag is undefined`.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a [`hostvars` magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

```
{{ hostvars['localhost']['git_tag'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

{{ hostvars['test-server']['git_tag'] }}