# Register variable usage among hosts in one playbook

Tags: ansible

In a single playbook, I'm working with two hosts and want to use one host variable into another. Like number of files in directory on different hosts. Is there way to do so in ansible

```
- hosts: abc
  tasks:
- name: Check 
  shell: ls -ltrh /tmp/test1/ | wc -l
  register : something_result


- hosts: cde
  tasks:
- name: True
  shell: ls -ltrh /tmp/test1/ | wc -l
  register: something2_result
  failed_when: something2_result != something_result
```

Comment: Edit the question and explain what would like to compare (directory content or something else).

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885216/ansible-use-fact-from-local-host-in-remote-host-template

Answer (score 0):

When you register a variable for a `shell` module the output of the command will be put into a substructure `output` as explained on the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html).

so for your code your have to compare `something_result.stdout` against `something2_result.stdout` at the `failed_when` keyword

Comment: this is the error I'm getting when trying to run as mentioned above. Looks like it is failing because something_result is a variable for different host..

Comment: fatal: [cde]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'something2_result != something_result' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (something2_result != something_result): 'something_result' is undefined"}

Comment: Can someone please help. It is still not working

Answer (score 0):

please try as below::

```
 - hosts: server1.com
   tasks:
 - name: do something
   shell: ls -ltrh /home | wc -l
   register : something_result
 - name: set fact
   set_fact:
     var1: "{{ something_result.stdout }}"
 - hosts: server2.com
   tasks:
 - name: do something
   shell: ls -ltrh /home | wc -l
   register: something2_result
   failed_when: ( something2_result.stdout != hostvars['server1.com']['var1'] )
```

Use set_fact to register the variable for the host. Then call the variable using "hostvars"

Comment: tried this error :
atal: [server2.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'hostvars['server1.com']['var1']  != something2_result.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (hostvars['server1.com']['var1']  == something2_result.stdout): \"hostvars['server1.com']\" is undefined"}

Comment: can you please post your playbook